# Java API: Data treatment

Tags: java, spring, api, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm building an API in Java, using Spring and Hibernate. My situation is:

I have a table with 3 foreign keys, many to one, as which ones can receive a null value. The problem:

When I'm going to save some data in this table and send a null-valued id to my API, I have a question about how to handle it... Because, in my model, I always have to set an instance of the foreign key model, right ? Ex: Releases -> Users

The releases table has a user_id, so I have in my Release model a "private User user;" and I must make a setUser, if I want to save a foreign key, so when I want to save a release, I must first search its record in the database, right? Ex: `User user = userRepository.findById(getUserId()).Get(); release.setUser(user);`

But what if the user_id comes `null` from my API? how do I do this? because, if `null`, it will give an error in the `findById` function. Would I have to fill the code with ifs checking if the value is empty before saving it? I don't think it would be ideal... I thought that my front could send a value of 0 if the user_id has to be `null`, then it wouldn't search a record, but it would give a problem in the `get()` function when trying to find it.

So my question is, what is the best way to treat a foreign key that can be empty and come with a `null` value in a Java api?

Thanks in advance.

So would I have to do situations like this to validate the ID every time? Using the generic exception, I don't need to worry, if the id is `null`

```java
@Service
public class CreditCardService 
{
    @Autowired
    private CreditCardRepository creditCardRepository;
    
    public CreditCard findById(Integer id)
    {
        try {
            return creditCardRepository.findById(id).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }     
    }
}
```

This is my service to convert data and save:

```java
@Service
public class ConvertService 
{
    @Autowired
    private CreditCardService creditCardService;
    
    /**
     * Convert data to release model type
     * 
     * @return Release
     */
    public Release convert(CreateReleaseValidator data)
    {
        Release release = new Release();

        release.setDescription(data.getDescription())
            .setStatus(data.getStatus())
            .setType(data.getType())
            .setValue(data.getValue())                
            .setCreditCard(creditCardService.findById(data.getCreditCardId()));
    
        return release;
    }
}
```

I just want to learn what the best practices are, I really appreciate it

Comment: If the foreign key could be empty (or some unknown key) you need to check and handle that. For an empty or null key just don't do any lookup, for an unknown key check the lookup returned something. In both cases you'd not have a user to link your entity to so you either have to save it without that (make the relation optional), use some fallback user (e.g. look up a default) or report an error to the caller.

Comment: As per your problem statement it looks like you need to make your relation optional and column as nullable so in case you receive null from caller, you can check if null then set null otherwise fetch value and set.

Comment: Whats the best way to make this validation? 

Something like: 

public Release findById(<Optional>Integer id) 
{
  if (id.isPresent()) {
     //then if the register not exist I treat in exception try catch, outside here
      Release release = releaseRepository.findById(id.get()).get();
      return release;
  }
return null;
}?

I dont know if its normal in java make this type of function every time

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would do something like this:

```
    public CreditCard findById(Integer id)
    {
        if (id != null) {
            return creditCardRepository.findById(id).get();
        } else {
            return null;
        }     
    }
```